# excel to Tableau Aggregation formula conversion

Tags: tableau-desktop

Can someone help me to convert the excel formula to use it in Tableau

=sum(aggr(SUM(distinct SALES_TEAM_SIZE),[SALES TEAM]))

Comment: Show some sample input data and what you want the output to look like for that sample

Answer (score 0):

In Tableau sums are automatically classified as aggregations.

I am not entirely sure what you data looks like but based off your question I will assume that *Sales Team Size* is an integer and *Sales Team* is a varchar or text field.

For simplicity of explanation I will describe this process by making three calculations:

1. First lets make a calculation to get the distinct count of *SALES_TEAM_SIZE* and name it [dc_sales_team_size]:

   ```
   COUNTD([SALES_TEAM_SIZE])
   ```
2. Now we'll make one to get the total number of *SALES TEAM* and call it [c_sales_team]

   ```
   COUNT([SALES TEAM])
   ```
3. Create one last calculated field, name it [st_total] and add these two new fields together.

   ```
   [dc_sales_team_size] + [c_sales_team]
   ```

Drag [st_total] to your worksheet.

Read more on [Tableau Aggregations here.](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_aggregation.htm)